# (Angular js) HTML page not loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i'm new on angular js.

I have this HTML page (dowloaded from tutorial)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- define angular app -->
<html ng-app="scotchApp">

<head>
  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

  <!-- SPELLS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#logout"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="main">

    <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    <div ng-view></div>

  </div>

  <footer class="text-center">
    <p>View the tutorial on <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating">Scotch.io</a></p>

    <p>View a tutorial on <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview">Animating Your Angular Single Page App</a></p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

with this script.js

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })

    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/logout', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/logout.html',
        controller  : 'logoutController'
    });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});

scotchApp.controller('logoutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Logout';
});
```

I also have 4 simple HTML pages (home, contact, about and logout) that have the same structure like this

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Contact Page</h1>

    <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

I've just added logout page,  the related tags in index.html and the route within the script.  but it isn't been loaded. I don't understand why.

Comment: What hasn't been loaded? What isn't working exactly?

Comment: Works fine in this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/B1j4fI?p=preview). Maybe check file paths and that they're all in the right directories.

Comment: In conjunction with what @MatthewCawley stated, the HTML file paths within your route definitions may need to be from the base of the application. Also remove `ng-controller="MainController"` because you are indicating the app should use that controller within your route definitions.

Comment: it works now. I don't know what happened yesterday. So, thanks a lot everyone.